# Access secondary hard drive from IP in Java application in Apache Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, ip, ip-address, tomcat8, hard-drive

I have a Java web application that has to access a file in a hard drive different than the one the application is installed in.

I have the address configured in my *Web.xml*, this data is accessed from the Java code.

```
<param-value>//USERNAME:PASSWORD@IP_ADDRESS/HARD_DRIVE_LETTER/FOLDER_NAME/</param-value>
```

USERNAME: *User of the computer I want to access to*
PASSWORD: *Password of the mentioned user*
IP_ADDRESS: *Internet Protocol v4 Address of the Computer*
HARD_DRIVE_LETTER: *I want to access to* ***J:*** *hard drive*
FOLDER_NAME: *Name of the folder I want to access*

I have tried this way with no result:

```
<param-value>//USERNAME:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/J:/Documents/</param-value>
```

I have been able to use this URL locally because my test computer had only one Hard Drive:

```
<param-value>//USERNAME:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/Documents/</param-value>
```

So I could access the files in *C:\Documents* with this method with no problem.

Now, I had to export my application to a different computer, so I had to install Apache Tomcat 8.0 (Version 8.0.30) in that computer, in Hard Drive *I:*
And the data that my application has to access is stored in Hard Drive *J:*

How can I properly entry the right URL to access the data from my application?

Comment: What's with that prefix `//USERNAME:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1`? Why not just use `J:/Documents/` and `java.io.File`?

Comment: In the last analysis, you should be, as @akarnokd says, using the correct drive letter and accessing as a file. *If* the host of the file is a different one, then map a network drive to a drive letter first

Comment: The main application I am modifying uses SMBFile to access the data.
That is why I require that pattern:
domain;user:password@IP_ADDRESS/Folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my own problem.
The issue was that I was not writing properly the name of the hard drive I wanted to access.

To know the real name (or shared name) of a resource, I had to search here:

Right click on Windows logo or Start button
Choose *"Manage Equipment"*
*System Tools* > *Shared Folders* > *Shared Resources*
Here you can see the promer *"Resource Name"* with its *"Folder Access Route"*
So, to access drive *J:*, I had to type the IP address of the computer + "/" + "**J$**"

```
<param-value>//USERNAME:PASSWORD@IP_ADDRESS/J$/FOLDER_NAME/</param-value>
```

In my code, I used SMBFile to access the file, so I had to create a String adding *"smb:"* to the beginning of that parameter:

```
String fileAddress = "smb:" + fileLocationParam;
```

Where I obtained "fileLocationParam" from the *Web.xml*

This way, I was able to access the file using SMBFile